# Reference a routine with different variables

Tags: delphi

Is it possible to have 2 references to a single routine, i.e. combine these somehow:

```
procedure SetUpGrid(AGrid: TStringGrid);
procedure SetUpGrid(AGrid: TJVStringGrid);


procedure SetUpGrid(AGrid: ??);
Begin
...
```

Would have two procedures but this one is identical and lengthy and only need to use the different grids for other procedures.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect `TJvStringGrid` is from the Jedi VCL. In that case it is a descendant of `TJvExStringGrid` which is a direct descendant of `TStringGrid`, and there is nothing special you need to do as one class (TJvStringGrid) descends from the other (TStringGrid).

You can just declare your procedure using the most common class, in this case TStringGrid:

```
procedure SetUpGrid(AGrid: TStringGrid);
```

and pass it an instance of TJvStringGrid.

For example:

```
procedure SetUpGrid(AGrid: TStringGrid);
begin
  // Whatever your code does to set up the grid.
end;

procedure TForm1.SomeGridToSetup;
var
  ASimpleTStringGrid: TStringGrid;
  AJediVclStringGrid: TJvStringGrid;
begin
  ASimpleTStringGrid := TStringGrid.Create(Self);
  AJediVclStringGrid := TJvStringGrid.Create(Self);

  SetUpGrid(ASimpleTStringGrid);
  SetUpGrid(AJediVclStringGrid);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if both have common anchestor which exposes all the functionality you need. Ie if both are descendants of `TCustomGrid` you'd use `procedure SetUpGrid(AGrid: TCustomGrid);`

Of course, since all objects descend from TObject you can use it but it would be somewhat useless as the TObject won't expose any properties / methods of the grid... you would have to test the input for the actual type like

```
procedure SetUpGrid(AGrid: TObject);
begin
  if(AGrid is TStringGrid)then begin
     ...
  end else if(AGrid is TJVStringGrid)then begin
     ...
  end
end
```

which somewhat cancels the idea of using only one procedure.

Answer (score 0):

If TStringGrid and TJvStringGrid are somehow "related", i.e. have the same base class, or one inherits from the other, then it is quite simple. Use that type as parameter type.

If this is not the case, it is not so easy. Generics won't help you, and using the utmostbase class, TObject won't be of any help either, since that doesn't have the methods you need.

**Solution one**

You might have luck using anonymous methods, and use these as parameter to your function, so you can call them inside the function:

```
type
  TGridFunc = reference to function: Integer;

procedure SetupGrid(AGridFunc: TGridFunc);
var
  ...
begin
  ...
  Error := AGridFunc;
  ...
end;
```

You use it like this:

```
var
  GF: TGridFunc;
  JvGrid: TJvStringGrid;
  VclGrid: TStringGrid;
begin
  ...
  SetupGrid(
    function: Integer
    begin
      ... do things with JvGrid ...
      Result := 0;
    end);

  SetupGrid(
    function: Integer
    begin
      ... do things with VclGrid ...
      Result := 1;
    end);

  ...
end;
```

That is a bit convoluted, and reminds a bit of dependency injection, but I see no other way.

**Solution two**

Oh wait, there is one other way: Define an interface type (say, IStringGrid) that has all methods you might need. Implement it twice, once as descendant of TJvStringGrid and once as descendant of TStringGrid, wrapping existing grids of the right type. SetupGrid would look like:

```
procedure SetupGrid(Grid: IStringGrid);
```

Now you can pass these implementations to SetupGrid:

```
SetupGrid(TStringGridWrapper.Create(Form1.StringGrid1));

SetupGrid(TJvStringGridWrapper.Create(Form2.JvStringGrid1));
```

Of course this only makes sense if you can reuse these wrappers or if SetupGrid is so complex that you don't simply want to write it twice. IOW, only if it is worth the trouble.

### UPDATE

I just checked, and apparently TJvStringGrid inherits from TJvExStringGrid, which inherits from TStringGrid in the VCL. So now it is quite easy:

```
procedure SetupGrid(AGrid: TStringGrid);
begin
  ...
  // things that equally apply to TStringGrid and TJvStringGrid can be done here. 
  if AGrid is TJvStringGrid then
  begin
    ...
    // things that only apply to TJvStringGrid can be done here.
    ...
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Of course the units for TStringGrid and for TJvStringGrid must both be in the uses clause of the implementation section or the interface section of the unit.

Comment: I left the original content, because I think the other solutions are valid for cases where the two classes do not share their ancestry.